# What is a Mudra and what do they mean?

Tags: vajrayana, art, iconography, mudra

In Buddhist iconography the figures are illustrated or depicted with various hand gestures.  The symbolic hand gestures are called mudras.  What is the significance of a Buddhist mudra? What are the various meanings for different popular mudras?

[image]

Courtesy of [Jordan](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/558939003722937255/)

[image]

Courtesy of [Asia Society](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nalanda#mediaviewer/File:Astasahasrika_Prajnaparamita_Avalokitesvara_Bodhisattva_Nalanda.jpeg)

Answer (score 3):

According to Dr. Robert Thurman:

> The mudra “is a sacred gesture symbolically expressing inner wisdom,
>   or, in tantra, a female consort for yogic practices that harness
>   sexual energies to the path.  Some of the main gestures we see in
>   Tibetan images are *abhaya*, the gesture of fearlessness, the right
>   hand held in from with open palm raised up: *dana*, the gesture of
>   giving, the right hand held open and downward;
>   *dharmacakrapravartana*, the teaching gesture, each hand held with thumb and index fingers touching and the other three fingers upraised,
>   the two hands touching each other in front of the heart center;
>   *dhyāna*, contemplation gesture, either one or both hands held flat in the lap; *trisharana*,  the Triple Refuge gesture, similar to the
>   teaching gesture, with the emphasis on the three upraised fingers,
>   representing the Buddha, Dharma, and Sangha; *tarjanī*, threatening
>   gesture, with either hand held forward in a fist, the index and little
>   fingers raised up; *varada*, boon-granting gesture, just like the
>   giving gesture; and *vitarka*,  analytic or fine discernment gesture,
>   like a one-handed teaching gesture, one hand held up with thumb and
>   index finger forming a circle, the other three fingers raised up.” [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnBux.jpg)

**Abhaya Mudra:**

[image]

Courtesy of [Acerca de Ernest Cappa](http://poetrysdays.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/introduccion-a-los-mudra/)

**Dana Mudra:**

[image]

Courtesy of [Angela Wheeler on Ink me](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/195202965072119688/)

The righthand is in the dana mudra gesture.

**Dharmacakrapravartana Mudra:**

[image]

Courtesy of [Acerca de Ernest Cappa](http://poetrysdays.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/introduccion-a-los-mudra/)

**Dhyāna Mudra:**

[image]

Courtesy of eric_m #dhyanamudra - Instagram

**Tarjanī Mudra:**

[image]

Courtesy of erinhosfield #tarjanimudra - Instagram

**Varada Mudra:**

[image]

Courtesy of [buddhabe #vitarka](http://www.tumblr.com/search/vitarka+mudra)

Right hand in varada mudra.

**Vitarka Mudra:**

[image]

Courtesy of [buddhabe #vitarka](http://www.tumblr.com/search/vitarka+mudra)

1. [Mandala: The Architecture of Enlightenment](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1570622973) by Leidy and Thurman pg 168

Answer (score 3):

If I can give an answer with reference to 5 Buddha mandala as I think it draws together the iconography into a satisfying whole.

As it's name suggests the 5 Buddha mandala 5 Buddhas at each compass point with one at the center. Each Buddha displays their own mudra. Each mudra points to a quality of that Buddha and thus to a quality of the enlightenment experience.

[image]

**1. Aksobhya The blue Buddha**

Mudra is the bhūmisparśa or earth touching mudra. The hand touches the earth. This points to the imperturbable.

[image]

**2. Ratnasambhava - the yellow Buhha**

Mudra is the dana or giving mudra. The hand points downward and out (shown by NeilD). This points to generosity.

**3. Amitabha - the red budda**

Mudra is the meditation or dhyana mudra. Hands together (show by NeilD). This obviously points to contemplation

**4. Amoghasiddhi - the green buddha**

Mudra is the fearlessness or abhaya mudra. Hand is up and poitn forward (shown by NeilD). This is self explanatory I think.

**5. Vairocana - the white buddha**

Mudra is the wheel-turning or Dharmacakrapravartana mudra (again shown by NeilD). This which fits his central place in the mandala, bringing all the other qualities together.

Comment: Where you able to find any images of the  trisharana mudra?  I found other mudras but not that one.  I would like to add an image of that to the answer.  Any help would be appreciated.  I like the context you added. :)

Comment: @NeilD I've put a put up of Aksobhya showing the mudra a bit more. I think I'll try to get decent pictures of all the buddhas up when I get a moment.

Comment: @Crab_Bucket Thanks for the additional picture.  I think you have a great idea.  The answers for this question need to include illustrations to help the readers.